# Remove level and all of its rows from pandas dataframe if one row meets condition

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a pandas dataframe that I would like to filter. I would like to remove the year and all of its rows when the temp for at least one row (i.e., `visit`) in that year is < 37. I am able to remove the specific row in 2014 where the temp is 36; however, I do not know how to make the entire year go away.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]], names=['yr', 
                                                                  'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['hr', 'temp'], names=['metric'])
data = pd.DataFrame([[96, 38], [98, 38], [85, 36], [84, 43]], index=index, 
                    columns=columns)
data

        metric  hr      temp    
yr      visit                       
2013    1       96      38  
        2       98      38  
2014    1       85      36  
        2       84      43
```

Desired Output:

```
        metric  hr      temp    
yr      visit                       
2013    1       96      38  
        2       98      38
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`groupby/filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) to remove groups based on a condition:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]], names=['yr', 'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['hr', 'temp']], names=['metric'])
data = pd.DataFrame([[96, 38], [98, 38], [85, 36], [84, 43]], index=index, columns=columns)

print(data.groupby(level='yr').filter(lambda x: (x['temp']>=37).all()))
```

yields

```
metric      hr temp
yr   visit         
2013 1      96   38
     2      98   38
```

Since the rows you wish to remove are grouped by `yr` and the `yr` is a level of the index, use `groupby(level='yr')`. For each group the `lambda` function is called with `x` set to the sub-DataFrame group. The group is kept when 
`(x['temp']>=37).all())` is `True`.

---

Note that [Wen's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638955/remove-level-and-all-of-its-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-if-one-row-meets-conditio/49639025?noredirect=1#comment86285951_49639025),

```
data.loc[(data['temp']>=37).groupby(level='yr').transform('all')]
```

is faster, particularly for large DataFrames, since `data['temp']>=37` computes the criterion in a vectorized way *for the entire column* whereas in my solution above, `(x['temp']>=37).all()` computes the criterion in a piecemeal fashion for each sub-DataFrame separately. Generally, vectorized solutions are faster when applied to large arrays or NDFrames instead of in a loop on smaller pieces.

Here is an example showing the difference in speed for a 1000-row DataFrame:

```
In [70]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).set_index(['A','B'])

In [71]: %timeit df.groupby(level='A').filter(lambda x: (x['C']>=5).all())
10 loops, best of 3: 46.3 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit df.loc[(df['C']>=37).groupby(level='A').transform('all')]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Just a alternative very similar to filter `data[data.temp.gt(37).groupby(level=0).transform('all').values]
`

Answer (score 0):

Using `.loc`:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
  [[2013, 2014], [1, 2]], names=['yr', 'visit'])

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['hr', 'temp']], names=['metric'])

data = pd.DataFrame([[96, 38], [98, 38], [85, 36], [84, 43]], 
                    index=index, columns=columns)

data.loc[[2013]]
```

Gives:

```
metric      hr  temp
yr   visit
2013 1      96    38
     2      98    38
```