# Remove index from MultiIndex dataframe if child index has column value meeting criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I had originally asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52389667/8146556), and I believe it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. I will do my best here to clarify my question and how I believe it is unique.

Given the following example `MultiIndex` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

first = ['A', 'B', 'C']
second = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
third = ['1', '2', '3']

indices = [first, second, third]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(indices, names=['first', 'second', 'third'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(len(first)*len(second)*len(third), 4)), index=index, columns=['Val1','Val2',' Val3', 'Val4'])
```

**Goal:** I would like to retain a specific `level=1` index (such as `'a'`) if the value of column `'Val2'` corresponding to index value `1` in `level=2` is greater than `5` for that `level=1` index. Therefore, if this criteria is not met (i.e. column `'Val2'` is less than or equal to `5` for index `1` in `level=2`), then the corresponding `level=1` index would be removed from the dataframe. If all `level=1` indices do not meet the criteria for a given `level=0` index, then that `level=0` index would also be removed. My previous post contains my expected output (I can add it here, but I wanted this post to be as succinct as possible for clarity).

Here is my current solution, the performance of which I'm sure can be improved:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)

output = pd.concat([grouped.get_group(key).groupby(level=1).filter(lambda x: (x.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, '1'], 'Val2']>5).any()) for key, group in grouped])
```

This does produce my desired output, but for a dataframe with 100,000's of rows, the performance is rather poor. Is there something obvious I am missing here to better utilize the under-the-hood optimization of `pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result as your example solution by doing the following:

```
df.loc[df.xs('1', level=2)['Val2'] > 5]
```

Comparing time performance this is ~15X faster (in my machine your example takes 36ms while this take 2ms).

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!